# Concatenating Attributes of Points in Same Location using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I have a single feature class that contains multiple points with the same location, but different names and text attributes, and I would like to concatenate the attributes together and merge the points down to a single point.

So a dataset like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+------+-----------+------------+
| ID | Lat | Lon | Name | Atribute1 | Attribute2 |
+----+-----+-----+------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |  60 |  60 | a    | a         | q          |
|  2 |  60 |  60 | b    | a         | r          |
|  3 |  61 |  61 | c    | a         | s          |
|  4 |  62 |  62 | d    | b         | t          |
|  5 |  62 |  62 | e    | b         | u          |
|  6 |  62 |  62 | f    | b         | v          |
|  7 |  63 |  63 | g    | c         | w          |
|  8 |  64 |  64 | h    | c         | x          |
|  9 |  65 |  65 | i    | c         | y          |
| 10 |  65 |  65 | j    | d         | z          |
+----+-----+-----+------+-----------+------------+
```

I want it to end up something like this:

```
+----+-----+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
| ID | Lat | Lon |  Name   | Atribute1 | Attribute2 |
+----+-----+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |  60 |  60 | a, b    | a         | q, r       |
|  3 |  61 |  61 | c       | a         | s          |
|  4 |  62 |  62 | d, e, f | b         | t, u, v    |
|  7 |  63 |  63 | g       | c         | w          |
|  8 |  64 |  64 | h       | c         | x          |
|  9 |  65 |  65 | I, j    | c, d      | y, z       |
+----+-----+-----+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I have tried a bunch of different methods to do things like run summary statistics, but that only does numbers or first/last not a concatenate.

I am currently working on ideas as to how to script it out in python, but I was hoping there is a tool which I am missing that will do this already. I am also not sure on what the best route to script it is either. I was thinking about looping through the original dataset, select by location, concatenate all the fields, and put them into the first point while deleting the rest. But not sure that would be the right method.

Comment: Use the Add XY Coordinates Tool, Export the table and concatenate in Excel, save as .csv file, import .csv and create xy events, export events to Shapefile or FC.

Comment: (1). Add field and label rows that are supposed to be grouped together. In your case for example the first two rows will be 1,1 then the 3rd 2 and the 4th -6th 3 etc...(2).Use pivot table in function in ArcGIS  (search for its exact name in ArcGIS) and pivot your data based on the newly added field at step 1.  (3). in the resulting pivoted dataset add three new fields for `Name`, `Attribute1` and `Attribute2`, specifiy the appropriate field types for your data.  (4). use field calculator on each new fields and concatenate the pivoted fields i.e for `Name` field -> [Name1.1] &","& [Name1.2]

Comment: While both of those are good suggestions, this is for multiple large datasets. A scriptable solution that does not require human intervention is the ideal solution. There are an unknown number of points in each location meaning who knows how many name fields there will end up being. And that really complicated the appending of the fields together. I imagine you could get a list of all fields, and then string match them, and create a list of fields to append, but that doesn't seem like a great idea either.

Comment: I would do this using simultaneous search and update cursors to determine points at the same location and then flatten out their field values.

Answer (score 3):

1. Calculate the X and Y coordinates into separate double fields.
2. Use the [Summary Statistics tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000) in the Analysis Toolbox->Statistics Toolset using the coordinate fields as Case fields (set up any other field as a summary field, but the summary does not really matter) to get a table with each unique point coordinate listed.
3. Use the [Make XY Event Layer tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_XY_Event_Layer/00170000006z000000/) in the Data Management Toolbox->Layers and Table Views Toolset to make the table into an in memory point feature class.
4. Use the [Spatial Join tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) in the Analysis Toolbox->Overlay Toolset with the following settings:

Target Features:  The Layer created by the Make XY Event Layer tool in step 3.

Join Features:  The original point feature class.

Out Features:  Provide the Workspace and Name of the output point feature class.

Join Operation:  Join_One_To_One.

Join Type:  Keep All

Field Mapping:  Successively Right click each field in the tool's fields list that you want to contain a list of values and change the Properties so that the output Field Type is Text, the Length is 255 (or a big enough value to contain all listed items without regard to uniqueness), the Merge Rule is Join, and the delimiter is a comma (or some other delimiter character(s) if the original field values actually include commas).

[image: Sample Spatial Join Field Properties Settings to Create a Join List of Values]

5. The output will contain the complete list of values from all of overlapping points in all of the fields where the Merge Rule was set to Join, but the listed values will not necessarily be sorted or unique.  To make each field contain a comma separated list of just unique and sorted values run a Python Field Calculation on each Join list field or use an UndateCursor on the feature class to read and write back to each Join list field with the function:

', '.join(map(str, sorted(set( !FieldName!.split(',')))))

Note: By using ', '.join(... to rebuild the list the formula above adds a space following each comma separating the listed values for formatting and appearance, but that can be changed to any delimiter character(s) you want to use.  If some of the actual values in the list were supposed to be whitespace characters it would be better to just use ','.join(...    Also ...split(',') should change the comma to whatever delimiter character(s) you actually used in the Spatial Join output field properties.